# How to restart sshd in OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, ssh, services

I have configured ssh keys for github. I have multiple ssh keys configured already.
I need to add new ssh keys for bitbucket. But it does not seem to be working.

How do i restart sshd in OSX Lion?

Answer (score 12):

> How do i restart sshd in OSX Lion?

You probably know this already, but I'll say to be complete: if you kill `sshd` processes you'll terminate active SSH sessions to the machine. The `sshd` daemon provides ssh access *to* your machine. It handles incoming ssh connections. Not outbound connections.

If `sshd` is really what you mean then...

Before you restart it, try sending it a SIGHUP signal so it re-reads all of its configuration. You can do that with

```
ps -ef | grep sshd | awk {'print $2'} | sudo xargs kill -HUP
```

If you really want to kill all the `sshd` process on the machine:

```
ps -ef | grep sshd | awk {'print $2'} | sudo xargs kill -KILL
```

## But try this stuff below first!

All that being said: if you're looking for keys for *outbound* sessions from the machine to be refreshed, killing `sshd` processes won't help you. What you really want to do is to add the new keys to the [ssh-agent](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) process with [ssh-add](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ssh-add/) -- that is usually sufficient to get new keys to be known to the agent.

The `ssh-agent` process handles all keyfile-based authentication for you. It's started automatically by Lion for each logged in user and it even integrates with Keychain.

If your new keyfile is `~/.ssh/bitbucket` you would add it like so:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

Now the key would be available to new ssh sessions initiated from the terminal. No need to kill or restart anything.